# Visual Studio 2015 Pro + Windows 10 + VirtualBox + 3D Acceleration

Tags: windows, visual-studio, 3d, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Why is Visual Studio 2015 Professional failing to launch on Windows 10 installed in VirtualBox VM, when enabling the 3D acceleration in VirtualBox settings?

The message shows: "Visual Studio 2015 stopping working ..."

VirtualBox is version 5.0.2 r102096.

---

EDIT:

After installing Guest Additions and enabling experimental Direct3D support, the problem is solved.
But VS 2015 seems to be a bit slow, will keep testing.

Comment: When I installed extenstion it was checked but still have this same problem. Is there something I need to do to enable it? My installer keeps crashing

Comment: You need to be more specific

Comment: What I am saying is even with 3D turned on I still cannot install Visual Studi 2015

Comment: Just ran into this issue today, but I am still running VirtualBox 4.3.30r101610. I had Guest Additions already installed with 3D support enabled, and could not get VS to install. Disabling 3D support and 2D video support allowed me to install. Having 3D support on seems to make whole VM slower than having it off. If I upgrade VirtualBox, I'll post back if I find that I can enable 3D support and have a workable VS install.

Answer (score 0):

I have some solutions that will fix the problem. First, I am assuming you are using Oracle VB. ON your virtual machine go to your virtual box and select System make your ram  1024MB or higher, this could help. Second solution, it might not be a problem with virtual box but it might be that you don't have Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 installed. Download it here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 . Then try to run visual studio. If doesn't work try reinstalling visual sudio here https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/

Comment: see edit above, the problem is solved (sort of). nobody runs desktop Windows 10 with 1GB of RAM. VC++ redist is installed during VS installation. Reinstalling takes bunch of time and is not even possible with 3D acceleration problem.